# Left Join from Python Dataframe to Postgre SQL Database with same Key

Tags: python, postgresql, left-join

i have a Python dataframe

```
Key   Number
1      23    
22     34
55     34
```

My PostgreSQL Database looks like this

```
Key Table1 Table2  
1    X
22   Y
55   Z
```

What i need is now is to join the Dataframe with the same Key to the SQL Database in the empty Column. So the SQL DB has to look like this afterwards,

```
Key Table1 Table2 
1    X    23
22   Y    34
55   Z    34
```

Thanks.

Comment: so, you want to write join in pandas and then write to SQL database? What have you tried so far? How does the tables in PSQL look like?

Comment: i have not found any similar problem yet. What i tried was so export the df to csv and then import it to the PSQL. But i want a direct way without the csv step. The Table looks like i wrote in the post and i want to attach the number to the PSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following with [pandas merge][1]:

```py
df

# Key   Number
#1      23    
#22     34
#55     34

import pandas as pd
sql_df = pd.read_sql(query ="some query", con =<your engine>) #Read the dataframe from the DB

merged = pd.merge(sql_df,df, left_on="Key", right_on="Key",how="left") #Merge it with our data frame (df)

merged.rename({"Number":"Table2"},inplace=True) #Rename the column to "Table2"
merged.to_sql("table_name", con=<your engine>, schema="SomeSchema",if_exists="replace",index=False) #Push it to DB, replace i


  [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
```